# Will disodium EDTA effectively destroy Tollens' reagent?

Tags: coordination-compounds

As I understand it, if I mix $\ce{[Ag(NH3)2]NO3}$ and $\ce{Na2EDTA}$ the silver will complex much more strongly with the EDTA than the ammonia, and the hydrogen ions will protonate the ammonia, leaving $\ce{AgEDTA^{3-} + 2NH4+ +NO3- + 2Na+}$, preventing the formation of silver nitride. Does that make sense? I'm concerned that the nitrate is incompatible with the EDTA somehow (that is, that it will oxidize something and break it apart).

Comment: Reaction is OK, but I don't get what you mean by "incompatible".

Comment: He may mean mutual reaction, that would occur in concentrated nitric acid only.

Comment: There would be needed review of complex stability constants. I am afraid for M+ ions and EDTA it would not be great, compared to ammonia.I would prefer acidification and silver recycling, e.g. by metallic zinc or solution based reduction agens.

Comment: Silver has been found to form complex with EDTA: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/222356275_Thermal_stability_and_bonding_in_the_silver_complexes_of_ethylenediaminetetraacetic_acid

Comment: @Nilay Ghosh I rather mean, if it's stability constant is high enough to avoid forming diamminsilver complex.